# Group by with case when

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have Projects - Issues, one to many relationship.

I want Pending issues and Completed issues for each project.

So, what I have done

```
SELECT
    a.id ,
    a.Name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.StatusId = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CompletedIssues,
    SUM(CASE WHEN b.StatusId != 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS PendingIssues
FROM 
Projects a
    JOIN Issues b
        ON a.ID = b.ProjectId
GROUP BY 
a.name, 
b.StatusId, 
a.ID
```

But it's not giving proper output. see below snap.

[image]

There are two separate rows for Completed and pending issues and sometimes more then 2 rows based upon Issues Status ID (See BT5).

> Is case when is wrong for this scenario?
>
> what is the proper way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your `group by`:

```
select p.id, p.Name, 
       sum(case when i.StatusId = 3 then 1 else null end) as CompletedIssues,
       sum(case when i.StatusId <> 3 then 1 else null end) as PendingIssues
from Projects p join
     Issues i
     on p.ID = i.ProjectId
group by p.name, p.id;
```

Note:  You may not want `else NULL`.  Normally, you want counts to be zero rather than `NULL`:

```
select p.id, p.Name, 
       sum(case when i.StatusId = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as CompletedIssues,
       sum(case when i.StatusId <> 3 then 1 else 0 end) as PendingIssues
from Projects p join
     Issues i
     on p.ID = i.ProjectId
group by p.name, p.id;
```

Also, I changed the table aliases to something more meaningful.  Don't use meaningless letters such as `a` and `b`.  Use table abbreviations.